# Swift iOS: Parsing of date from a string does not work for some devices. so weird

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

From the debugger it shows that the date string is "2017-08-01 00:00:00" and I passed the correct format too. But the dateFormatter.date part always fail (return nil) for 1 device. But some its working for simulator and other iphone devices.
Im using swift3

[image]

[image: iPhone 7 that fails]

Comment: You may want to look at this [thread](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1480/_index.html) to understand more about why it may not be working in this specific device.

Comment: @PuneetSharma thanks

Answer (score 10):

Try to set your locale:

```
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```